# how do i dissable a js function with mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm currently working on the project of mine and i have made a horizontal scrolling website.

what the problem seems to be is that when i have a scrollable div (vertically) in my horizontal webpage i can't scroll it vertically anymore.

this is the website: [ShareApe 3.0](http://m.shareape.com/)

i have tried to make a mouseover event to override this scrip but i cant get it to work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "section",
    responsiveFallback: 600
  });
});
</script>
```

so what i want to do is when your mouse hovers over the file selection "Drag & Drop files" part of the website i want this function to be disabled.

Manny thanks for your time!

update:

i have used this working code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fileUpload').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
</script>
```

its working but not for Firefox.

so i have tried to add some code and its not working for me:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fileUpload').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});

var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (slideshow.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
slideshow.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, rotateimage)

else if (slideshow.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, rotateimage, false)

</script>
```

Patrick Falize

Comment: `ShareApe` sounds an awful lot like `Share Rape`

Comment: if you can provide me a better name than that with an available .com domain thad would be awsome.

Comment: I also noticed that I just have to attach `?d=1` to a URL in order to bypass the download timer. You might want to fix that ^.^

Comment: thank you. i will fix thad one shortly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#fileUpload').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: the strange thing is thad if i put this into the chrome console it works but if i put it in <script></script> it wont work :S hows that?

Comment: Are you putting it within a dom ready wrapper? Does the element exist when you're attempting to bind it?

Comment: the only thing is... its working perfectly on chrome and safari but not on firefox

Comment: Looks like you'll need to listen for two events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser

Comment: i have tried this:

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fileUpload').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
    });
    
    var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
 
if (slideshow.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
    slideshow.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, rotateimage)
else if (slideshow.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
    slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, rotateimage, false)

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me on all browsers i just had to add some code for firefox.

Firefox doesn't support .onmousewheel, you have to use the DOMMouseScroll event instead:

```
$(document).on( "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

oke so i figure it out. firefox has no problems with e.stopPropagation(); but the problem was with the moudewheel function. so i added "DOMMouseScroll" to the .on and it worked like a sharm!