# Mousewheel event in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, mousewheel

Mousewheel event is not triggering in Firefox, am using the `jquery.mousewheel` plugin, but even without it it was working fine in all browsers except Firefox.
Here is my code:

```
    $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
            console.log(123);
            //some code...
   });
```

[Live example here](http://wheniamplaying.com/mspa/)

Any suggestions? Many thanks for all answers...

Comment: Could you simply bind to `scroll` instead? Support [appears to be better](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html), although it fires in more situations. Additionally, the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel) event has deprecated `mousewheel` in Firefox. Could the mousewheel plugin not be loading correctly?

Comment: I can't use that in this situation, as there is no scrolling on that page... The mousewheel should just change the page on that example...

Comment: Possibly already answered [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16788995/2032064)

Comment: I've already seen that, but it didn't helped...

Comment: Could you post un-minified, unbuilt source? I'm looking through your `main-built.js` and it looks really weird, not to mention your website never loads a jQuery module OR the mousewheel plugin module.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was trying that on localhost. Will upload now this version but not minified.

Comment: Here is the home view: http://wheniamplaying.com/mspa/js/views/home.js Last part of the render method is causing the issue...

Answer (score 0):

[jquery.mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js#L74) is not loading properly.

You can verify this by going to your website, opening the developer console, and typing
`$.fn.mousewheel` or `$.fn.unmousewheel` and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Both return `undefined`.

It's possible this may work if you capture your `mousewheel` dependency as a parameter to your anonymous module, but if I'm being totally honest, every time I have to deal with jQuery plugins and requireJS, I just give up on the scoped modules and let jQuery do it's nasty thing in the global scope (which is why I use jQuery less and less these days).

As for why it worked in other browsers, I believe Webkit is the only engine to have added support for `mousewheel`.  Because the jquery.mousewheel plugin is not loading, other browsers are deferring to their native implementations.

Comment: Thats not the latest version online with the jquery.mousewheel plugin included, thats why its returning undefined... Sorry for confusion, I shouldn't post that link at all... I wanted to upload the latest version, but then I realised that I had to upload the new backend and new database, because there are loads of differences between that version and the latest one which i have on local...

Answer (score 0):

In older FF versions, you can bind mousewheel-event using pure JavaScript and `DOMMouseScroll`:

```
document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function(){ console.log(123); }, false);
```

Note, that `DOMMouseScroll`-event is deprecated. In newer Version, use `wheel`-event instead:

```
document.body.addEventListener("wheel", function(){ console.log(123); }, false);
```