# jQuery disable scroll doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code in other projects and it works fine. I don't know what is wrong in my code. It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

This is my code:

```js
$('body').on({
  'mousewheel': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/y8fLs43h/).

The jQuery version in my project is 1.11.3.

Comment: this does not diable scroll, lot of actions would trigger window scroll, such as a "down key"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers have there default "scroll-overflow" not on the body. Instand it is on html or document. Try `$('html')` or `$(document)` for example. That could help

Comment: I mean more or less the scollfunction itself in "scroll-overflow"

Answer (score 3):

you could take CSS approach with:

```
body {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or here's what i have working in Firefox:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble = false;
    return false;
}, false);
```

you can see my example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qn75a76q/1/

Comment: I need to do that with jquery. I know about css disabling

Answer (score 2):

I quote this from another answer:

> Firefox doesn't recognize "mousewheel" as of version 3. You should use
>   "DOMMouseScroll" instead for firefox.
>
> check this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml

Original answer here: [Mousewheel event not triggered in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser)