# Mousewheel doesnt work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I have been trying to figure out why my smoothscroll function doesn't work in firefox? It works fine in other browsers like chrome, Microsoft Edge. Can someone help me out, please. Please check this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWPaNx

```
function smoothScroll(time, distance) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var scrollTime = time;
    var scrollDistance = distance;

    $window.on("wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 80 || -event.originalEvent.detail / 3;

        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta * scrollDistance);

        TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
            scrollTo: {
                y: finalScroll,
                autoKill: true
            },
            ease: Power4.easeOut,
            overwrite: 5
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Your code works. You have forgotten to add this plugin: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js

Comment: @Phil Thanks for that, but it still doesnt work in firefox. Check the updated pen please https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWPaNx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll behavior in firefox is a little bit weird to me.

Here is a discussion i've found [mousewheel event is not triggering in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser)

```
function smoothScroll(time, distance) {

  // added this
  var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
  var scrollEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"

  var $window = $(window);
  var scrollTime = time;
  var scrollDistance = distance;

  // insert scrollEvent var
  $window.on(scrollEvent, function(event) {

    // added this (check if firefox)
    if (!isFirefox) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 80 || -event.originalEvent.detail / 3;

    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta * scrollDistance);

    // changed window
    TweenMax.to(window, scrollTime, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: finalScroll,
        autoKill: true
      },
      ease: Power4.easeOut,
      overwrite: 5
    });

  });
}

smoothScroll(1.1, 110);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does work but its pretty glitchy, but it does answer the question so.