# Force other div to scroll on my `wheel`

Tags: javascript, css

In the following snippet I have to `div`s. I want to sync their position when I try to scroll any of them. When the second div is scrolled, I'm changing `transform` of the first one and it works. But the first div is never scrolled. I've tried to pass `mousewheel` event to the second one, but it didn't work.

And I can't make `section` scrollable - it's just a simplified example.

```js
// This code works
// `.labels` moves together with scroll of `.scrollable`
document.querySelector(".scrollable").addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var dy = this.scrollTop;
  document.querySelector(".labels").style.transform = "translateY(" + -dy + "px)";
});

// This code does NOT work
// I want `.scrollable` to be scrolled when I try to scroll `.labels`
document.querySelector(".labels").addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
  console.log(Date.now());
  document.querySelector(".scrollable").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(e.type, e));
});
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 8em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 .25em;
}

.scrollable {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.labels {
  background: silver;
}

.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="labels">
    Label 1<br>
    Label 2<br>
    Label 3<br>
    Label 4<br>
    Label 5<br>
    Label 6<br>
    Label 7<br>
  </div><div class="scrollable">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br>
    Line 3<br>
    Line 4<br>
    Line 5<br>
    Line 6<br>
    Line 7<br>
  </div>
</section>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750420/178988)

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT]**
Consider reading this other SO question if you intend to use `mousewheel` event on Firefox: [mousewheel event is not triggering in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser)

**[EDIT 2]**
New edits to the code snippet, check the comments above to understand the context.

---

There is an issue with css, where you need the `labels` element to be scrollable, and to sync the scroll between the two elements you can simply use `scrollTop`.

I've modified you example to make it work:

```js
var scrollableEl = document.querySelector(".scrollable");
var labelsEl = document.querySelector(".labels");

scrollableEl.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  labelsEl.style.transform = `translateY(${ -scrollableEl.scrollTop }px)`;
  e.preventDefault();
});

labelsEl.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
  scrollableEl.scrollTop += (e.deltaY / 2);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 8em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 .25em;
}

.scrollable {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.labels {
  background: silver;
}

.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="labels">
    Label 1<br>
    Label 2<br>
    Label 3<br>
    Label 4<br>
    Label 5<br>
    Label 6<br>
    Label 7<br>
  </div><div class="scrollable">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br>
    Line 3<br>
    Line 4<br>
    Line 5<br>
    Line 6<br>
    Line 7<br>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've created a new class to be able to reuse the css, so expect the javascript query selector to pickup the element from `.scrollable--pane` class instead.

Comment: 1. `labelsEl.addEventListener('mousewheel'` - seems like you need `scroll` instead of `mousewheel` here. 2. You are making visible scrollbar on the first element, it shouldn't be there. 3. Unfortunately it doesn't help me, as in real situation there is no common container. PS: Anyway, upvoted the answer as it is nice.

Comment: 1. I've mantained the `mousewheel` since that was the one in question title, assumed that was important, but both work.  2. Maybe that should be part of your question in first place ;) 3. I'll edit my answer to try to match your needs

Comment: I've tried this: `document.querySelector(".labels").addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
  document.querySelector(".scrollable").scrollTop += e.deltaY;
});` but the difference beetween native scroll and emulation is great :(

Comment: Please check the update to see if it solves your issue

Comment: Looks almost fine in Chrome, but absolutely awful in FF (FF 55.0.2 x64 Linux Mint).

Comment: That is a different question/problem, which I've already pointed to a solution in the first edit. Please consider looking at the mentioned SO answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159932/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-a-m).

Answer (score 1):

this is `CSS` only solution.. take a look @CSS panel, simple if you can apply it in your surroundings

we only `shift` `.scrollable` element to the left with this:

```
margin-left: -60px;
padding-left: 60px;
```

```js
// This code works
// `.labels` moves together with scroll of `.scrollable`
document.querySelector(".scrollable").addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var dy = this.scrollTop;
  document.querySelector(".labels").style.transform = "translateY(" + -dy + "px)";
});
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 8em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 .25em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollable {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: -60px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.labels {
  background: silver;
}

.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="labels">
    Label 1<br>
    Label 2<br>
    Label 3<br>
    Label 4<br>
    Label 5<br>
    Label 6<br>
    Label 7<br>
  </div><div class="scrollable">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2<br>
    Line 3<br>
    Line 4<br>
    Line 5<br>
    Line 6<br>
    Line 7<br>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Nice answer. I guess this would not fix the issue if the div are in different parents as mentioned by the SO in comments.

Comment: ohh,, they are not in `section` both? .. and your answer man,, that thing with `e.deltaY / 2` thing is craaazy cleaver :)