# Cross-broswer support - Mouse scroll controlling next/prev Bootstrap carousel slide

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, mouseevent, carousel

I found an example that I want to use but am not sure how to adapt this code for the Bootstrap carousel controls. https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

I am using the code below, but it only works in Chrome, so I was hoping to adapt it with the other code. I thought it would be straight forward but my attempts have not worked.

```
$('.carousel').bind('wheel', function(e){
   if(e.originalEvent.deltaY > 50) {
      $(this).carousel('next');
   }
   else if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < -50) {
      $(this).carousel('prev');
   }
});
```

**-------UPDATE--------**

I found the answer on another thread that worked well across different browsers: [mousewheel event is not triggering in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser)

Here is the code adapted for my needs, mouse scrolling to control the next / previous slides on my Bootstrap 3 Carousel. Hope that helps anyone!

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(event){
// deltaY obviously records vertical scroll, deltaX and deltaZ exist too


if(event.originalEvent.deltaY > 50){
   // wheeled down
   $('.carousel').carousel('next')

}
else if(event.originalEvent.deltaY < -50) {
    // wheeled up
    $('.carousel').carousel('prev')
}

return false; //to disable page scrolling
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and have updated my original post.