# How to bind mousewheel event in Blazor working with Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, blazor, mousewheel, blazor-webassembly

We want to write code for an mousewheel-event on an div-container. Using the following code works fine in Browsers Edge and Chrome:

```
<div id="scroll-container" @onmousewheel="MouseWheelEventHandler">
    [...]
</div>

@code 
{
    private async Task MouseWheelEventHandler()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Scroll"); // works in Chrome and Edge, but not in FF
    }
}
```

But the `MouseWheelEventHandler` is not firing in Firefox.

Regarding this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser) with JavaScript we had to bind the mousewheel by `DOMMouseScroll`. (`DOMMouseScroll` is deprecated and `wheel` would do the job in future). This post is a solution for JavaScript, but not blazor.

```
document.getElementById("scroll-container").addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function(){...}, false);
```

How can I bind the mouse-scroll event for FF in Blazor Web Assembly?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser) SO question. It's the same reason.

Comment: I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848965/7095512) in the same SO question Eldar posted.

Comment: @Eldar: Please read my question. My problem is not JavaScript which solution is already known to me. My querstion targets an solution for blazor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mousewheel event is not triggering in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser)

Comment: @Quango: As you can see in my question, I already have mentioned your posted link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For firefox you have to add the event onwheel:

```
<div id="scroll-container" @onmousewheel="MouseWheelEventHandler" @onwheel="MouseWheelEventHandler">
    [...]
</div>

@code 
{
    private async Task MouseWheelEventHandler()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Scroll");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/csqrf9rh)